# How to run ASP.NET 5 without opening a page in the browser

Tags: asp.net-core

Prior to ASP.NET 5, there used to be an option in Visual Studio 2015 in the project properties | Web page for the start action not to open a page when running the web app. This allowed you to have an existing page open in the browser and just refresh it.

This option has now disappeared, resulting in a new browser page being opened every time I hit run, even though I have a page open at the correct URL etc. ready to be refreshed.

How can I get the previous behaviour?

Comment: You are looking under the "Web" section of the project properites?

Comment: There's no "Web" section in VS 2015 for an ASP.NET 5 project.

Answer (score 15):

In the Debug page of the project properties there's a checkbox "Launch URL" or “Launch browser” in later versions of VS. Unchecking it prevents VS from launching a page in the browser.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Just a note that in VS2019 this option is in the same place but renamed as "Launch browser". Turning this off allowed me to run my .net core API in a "headless" mode.